# bcrypt algorithm failed to login

Tags: php

I use

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
```

for my signup form. It's okay in database save perfectly, but can't login.

This is my login function

```
public function Login($user, $password)
{
    try {
        $db = DB();
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM members WHERE user=:user AND password=:password");
        $query->bindParam("user", $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data = $this->query->single(); 
        $getpass = $data['password'];
        $passv = password_verify($password, $getpass);
        $query->bindParam("password", $passv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            return $result->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

EDIT:

login.php

```
<?php

// Start Session
session_start();

// Database connection
require __DIR__ . '/database.php';
$db = DB();

// Application library
require __DIR__ . 'inc/functions.php';
$app = new DemoLib();


// check Login request
if (!empty($_POST['login'])) {

    $user = trim($_POST['user']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if ($user == "") {
        echo 'Please enter username.';
    } else if ($password == "") {
        echo 'Please enter password.';
    } else {
        $id = $app->Login($user, $password); // check user login
        if($id > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id; // Set Session
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'Wrong data.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the column where you're saving the hash at least 60 characters? If not, you will never be able to login as hashing requires that size of column in your database. To be safe make the column `VARCHAR (254)10th or `TEXT`

Comment: I make it varchar(255), but can't login again.

Comment: Did you register the password again, after changing the column size?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is in code. Do you look at him?

Comment: Somebody to help?

Comment: Do not select the password  like this `AND :password` because you're not sending the hash in this query.

Comment: Okay, but how to create the code to get hash and verify from database? I'm sorry but cant do this alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to try to match the password during the query as matching the hash would not work. In order to verify the password you will want to do something like this:

```
public function Login($user, $password)
{
    try {
        $db = DB();
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user=:user"); // get everything for the user
        $query->bindParam("user", $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //$data = $this->query->single(); 
        $data = $query->execute();
        $getpass = $data['password'];
        $passv = password_verify($password, $getpass);

        if ($passv) { // if the password is good
            return $data['id'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But why show me this error:            Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /home/slaserx/public_html/inc/functions.php on line 12  in this line is    $data = $this->$query->single();

Comment: I assumed that was the line you used to execute the query. If it isn't, remove that line and use `$query->execute()` I have no idea where you got your line 12 from.

Comment: When I use, your edited code show me this error: Notice: Undefined variable: data. If I remove // before $data = $this->$query->single(); 
it's show me same error. Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string on line 7 :(

Comment: Thank you very much! Now doesn't show errors, but can't login again. Show me this: Wrong data. I edited my post with login.php. Problem is in code. In database my hash is "$2y$10$hVNZRzdniIDxc7vmIAWKYeOmge/I3eGCMwxylyVcsOZVQk/mVmdBq" and column password is varchar(255). I'm so sorry for my not knowledge. I have to learn a lot

Comment: How are you setting `$id`?

Comment: In same way, I don't change nothing in my login.php.

Comment: What should the id be? Is it greater than 0? What do you have in the database?

Comment: Table  `members` (`id`, `user`, `password`, `email`, `ip`, `date`) VALUES

(15, 'test', '$2y$10$hVNZRzdniIDxc7vmIAWKYeOmge/I3eGCMwxylyVcsOZVQk/mVmdB‌​q', 'test@gmail.com', '::1', '23 March, 2017, 17:15:01');

Comment: Can you check the value of `$id` it the point it gets returned? Just echo it out.

Comment: I try with  echo id; after echo 'Wrong data.'; but returns me nothing. What I should do?

Comment: Without being able to examine the code more closely and add break points where needed it would be hard for me to say. I'd start with `print_r($data)` right after you execute the query. Output `$data` at several different steps to make sure it isn't getting unset somewhere.

Comment: When I use `var_dump($getpass);` returns me: `NULL`. But thanks to you I came to success. I make code this way: `$query->execute(); $data = $query->fetch(); $getpass = $data['password'];` and I login success. I can't explain how much I appreciate your help. Thank you very much!!!!!